# transision() causes Uncaught TypeError with D3 version 7.2.1

Tags: javascript, npm, d3.js

I have selected svg element (circle) and I want to apply a transition on it. When I try to apply transition on the circle I get "Uncaught TypeError: circle.transition is not a function".

I've written this code:

```
import * as selection from '../node_modules/d3-selection/src/index.js';

const RENDER_AREA_ID = "#renderArea";
let svg = selection.select(RENDER_AREA_ID).append("svg")
    .attr("width", document.querySelector(RENDER_AREA_ID).offsetWidth)
    .attr("height", document.querySelector(RENDER_AREA_ID).offsetHeight);
let circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("cx", 10)
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("stroke", "black");
circle.transition().attr("cx", 100); // here I get the TypeError
```

I've tried D3 version 4.x (avalible on this link: https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js) and the transition worked just fine. I face the issue while using version 7.2.1.

My question is: *What could be possibly causing the Uncaught TypeError?*

**UPDATE:** I've just find out that the issue is somehow associated with npm. When I access D3 through this link: https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js, then the transition works. But when I use d3 package from npm then the issue occurs.

Comment: What exactly does `animationUtils.getSVG()` return, i.e. what's the type of `svg`?

Comment: `select("renderArea")` and the two `document.querySelector("renderArea")` are probably not what you want, these will target a `<renderArea>` element. What you want is `"#renderArea"`.

Comment: @Kaiido you‘re right. I didn't copy it from my code and made an error while rewriting it. There is "#renderArea" in my code. Code sample is fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: @altocumulus getSVG function returns an object of 'svg' type (contained in a div)

Comment: question updated

Comment: The `d3-selection` package [does not depend](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/package.json#L36-L42) on `d3-transition` an has, therefore, no `transition()` property. That property is [added](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/main/src/selection/index.js#L6) to the selection object by the `d3-transition` package. You need the latter package for your code to work. Since the main bundle comprises all modules the error is inherently resolved when using the bundle.

Comment: @altocumulus So based on your comment I've tried bundle the library using browserify but got in a dead end again. Please see my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70476507/issue-with-using-browserify-to-bundle-d3-library