# Issue with using browserify to bundle D3 library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bundle, browserify

I want to learn D3 library. So I've installed it via npm. After a while I encountered an issue while applying transition on a svg object (see my original question here: [transision() causes Uncaught TypeError with D3 version 7.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447766/transision-causes-uncaught-typeerror-with-d3-version-7-2-1?noredirect=1#comment124545105_70447766)). I was adviced to bundle up the library to solve the issue.

I've been struggling with bundling D3 library using browserify. I've done these steps:

1. Used require function in a module file and give it as an argument the library name ("d3")
2. Referenced the module file and bundle.js file in a html document
3. In a directory containing the module file ran command: browserify module.js > bundle.js

After I ran the command I got this:

....\node_modules\d3\src\index.js:1
export * from "d3-array";
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

I'm completely clueless what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I give you a solution I want to give you the context to the actual problem.

Browserify allows you to combine multiple javascript files into one file. This really just saves you from needing to include multiple `<script>` tags in your html.

From my perspective it is a cleaner, simpler version of webpack/rollup but, less versatile.

D3 appears to be written in a version of javascript that supports import/export statements and uses Rollup to convert it to vanilla javascript that the browser (and browserify) can understand.

## The Answer

Import the final version of d3 that is transpiled already.

```js
const d3 = require('d3/dist/d3');


// do something with d3 here
const targetElem = d3.select('#target');

targetElem.text('HELLO WORLD');
```

Comment: So thus it's transpiled already means that I don't need to use any bundle tool and I just use require? I've tried this and got this message in the terminal: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. I've also updated my question with the first paragraph to better specify my motivation to bundle the library and using require.

Comment: Close, the D3 package is already transpiled into a format the browser can understand. However, your code with the `require` statement still needs to be transpiled by browserify. 

So do the same thing you were doing before just require `d3/dist/d3` instead of just `d3`. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Yea, I understand now. :) I'm complete newbie in a world of JS and I'd like to ask another question: Isn't there another more elegant way how to make D3 installed via npm work or is it mandatory to use require and a bundle tool?

Comment: You can use a `<script>` tag. something like `<script src="node_modules/d3/dist/d3><script>`  or use the cdn they provide on their getting started page. `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>`. But, yeah if you want to use `require` or `import` you'll need something to transpile it to javascript the browser can understand one way or another.

Comment: I'll try all the options you've provided and choose the most suitable for me. Thank you for your time and affort it was very helpful. :)